# Displaying large list from flask to html table no responding

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I pass the click signal through ajax , and get a list from the flask route, then append to the html table. however, when the list size exceeds 20000, the page will pop up a window and tell me to wait or close, no matter how long I wait, the result doesn't seems to come out, I don't think 20000 is a big number, and don't know if it's the problem of browser memory, any advice would help, thanks!

*this code works when the number of elements in list = 10000

flask code

```
@app.route('/get_tag', methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_tag():
if request.method == 'POST':
    point_list = ["123"]*100000
return jsonify({'taglist':point_list})
```

js code

```
            $("#search-tag").on('click',function(event){
            
            $.ajax({
              type : 'POST',
              url : "/get_tag",
              data:{
                text:$('#query').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
            $("#tabletest > tr").remove();
            for(i in data.taglist){
                var tr;
                tr= '<td><input type="checkbox" style="width: 20px;" class="checkchild"></td>'+ '<td>'+data.taglist[i]+'</td>';
                $("#tabletest").append('<tr>'+tr+'</tr>');
                }
              }

            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

html code

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%; font-size: 20px;" id="tabletest">

</table>
```

Comment: since 10k works and 20k doesnt... it probably cant handle that much...
something you could look into is streaming the results... as they come, you append and it can already "discard" it... so, memory wise, it will be limited only by how big the table will be...

Comment: either this, or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589120/jquery-and-appending-large-amounts-of-html the problem might be in jquery itself... from what i saw... maybe try to append less times (by batching it)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why the loop using jquery is extremely slow, so I changed the loop to the python backend, it's like 100 times faster.

flask backend

```
@app.route('/get_tag', methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_tag():
    if request.method == 'POST':

    point_list = ["123"]*100000

    result= ""

    for idx, i in enumerate(point_list):
      tr= '<td><input type="checkbox" style="width: 20px;" class="checkchild"> 
      </td>'+ '<td>'+i+'</td>'
    result += '<tr>'+tr+'</tr>';

return jsonify({'taglist':result})
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search-tag").on('click',function(event){
            
            $.ajax({
              type : 'POST',
              url : "/get_tag",
              data:{
                text:$('#query').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
            $("#tabletest > tr").remove();

              $("#tabletest").append(data.taglist);
              
              }

            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```